# TwitterKit Timeline not loading

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, timeline

I have installed TwitterKit via CocoaPods due to it not being available in the Fabric OSX app. I'm trying to get a timeline view integrated into the app. It acts like it's loading but never shows any output in the console and never actually loads anything.

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit
import Fabric

class updatesTVC: TWTRTimelineViewController{

convenience init() {
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    let dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "resurrectionwv", apiClient: client)
    self.init(dataSource: dataSource)
}

}
```

Comment: Images didn't save to the original question. Here are some screenshots of what I have set up. 

["Storyboard"](http://imgur.com/a/TMXCI)
["ViewController"](http://imgur.com/a/r7hnQ)
["Simulator"](http://imgur.com/a/5Y2wy)